# Cannot install QAML Builder Plugin for QAFE platform in eclipse kepler

Tags: eclipse, amazon-s3, oracleforms

I am trying to evaluate QAFE software for converting Oracle Forms to HTML5 based web application. As described in QAFE website, successfully installed QAFE platform which includes eclipse-kepler. Next while trying to install QAML builder plugin through the update site https://s3.amazonaws.com/qafe-downloads/update-site/4.3/site.xml, getting the following error.

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>   Software currently installed: QAML Builder 2.6.0.0 (graphical_qaml_builder_feature.feature.group 2.6.0.0)
>   Missing requirement: QAML Builder 2.6.0.0 (graphical_qaml_builder_feature.feature.group 2.6.0.0) requires 'qafe.qaml.builder [2.6.0.0]' but it could not be found

Looks like some dependency is missing in the update site.
Can someone please help me identify if i have missed anything?

Update site - https://s3.amazonaws.com/qafe-downloads/update-site/4.3/site.xml

Plugin Name - UI Designer Tools --> QAML Builder

Answer (score 0):

Tried re-installing QAFE platform bundle from scratch in a different location.
That was successful and the eclipse-kepler bundled in it had QAML builder plugin installed by default. There was no need to install it through any update site.